# Send mail via MailGun in CakePHP

Tags: email, cakephp, mailgun

i run a cloud app (using CakePHP) on Rackspace and i wanna send emails using cakephp.
I used this: https://github.com/kochb/cakephp-mailgun
but it returns me an

```
 "Could not send email.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred."
```

error.
The way i try to send an email is with the following code:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();


          $from = $this->request->data['Mail']['from'];
          $to = ($this->request->data['Mail']['to']);
          $subject = $this->request->data['Mail']['subject'];
          $message = $this->request->data['Mail']['message'];

                $Email->sender($from, 'TestName');
                $Email->from($from)
                    ->bcc($to)  
                    ->replyTo($from)
                    ->subject($subject)
                    ->send($message);



                    $this->Session->setFlash('On the way to recipient');
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
```

I have edited the Config/Email.php file inserting the MailGun API credentials etc.

What's possibly going on? Can you find out why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try defining the "from", "to", "subject", etc by hand? I literally copied your example, but set those parameters, and the message sent without issue. Here's a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/travelton/6160051).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I was having the same errors you were)*

The `BasicTransport` didn't have the right "pre-processing" nor the appropriate response handling.

I copied over the functionality from `CurlTransport` and it works for me now.

Specifically, we needed:

```
    $post = array();
    $post_preprocess = array_merge(
        $email->getHeaders(array('from', 'sender', 'replyTo', 'readReceipt', 'returnPath', 'to', 'cc', 'bcc', 'subject')),
        array(
            'text' => $email->message(CakeEmail::MESSAGE_TEXT),
            'html' => $email->message(CakeEmail::MESSAGE_HTML)
        )
    );
    foreach ($post_preprocess as $k => $v) {
        if (! empty($v)) {
            $post[strtolower($k)] = $v;
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
    $response = $http->post($url, $post, $request);
    if ($response === false) {
        throw new SocketException("Mailgun BasicTransport error, no response", 500);
    }

    $http_status = $response->code;
    if ($http_status != 200) {
        throw new SocketException("Mailgun request failed.  Status: $http_status, Response: {$response->body}", 500);
    }
```